# Cypress Chrome Conflicting With Ubuntu 16.04 Default Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

This is more a configuration question for cypess. Since I've installed cypress, every time I try to open an external link (from an email, or by clicking a link in another app running on my Ubuntu). The chrome browser opens but it's configured like when I run Cypress.
[image]

An this is my "usual" chrome browser

[image]

As you can see there are no extension or bookmarks and my google account is not logged in. Also I cannot visit any page and I have this message that says that chrome is being controlled by automated software (Cypress).

The only way I can get my old google chrome to run is by typing

```
google-chrome
```

on the terminal.

It feels like I have 2 versions of Chrome installed but I don't know how to make the one without Cypress the default. If a go to setting on both browser instances they both say that chrome is the default browser. It's a bit annoying to no be able to click external links and copy/paste them to the chrome I was used to have opened.

Has anybody experienced this issue and have a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

For some reason, cypress created a desktop entry in

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

so I just did

```
rm  ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.dektop
```

and the problem went away!